# Populate Jenkins choice parameters from a JSON file using

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins, my requirement is to use the Build parameters. Where I want to populate the choice parameter from a JSON file.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "_choice parameter_"? _Active Choices P._, _Active Choices Reactive P._ ,_Extended Choice P._, _Extensible Choice_, _Persistent Choice P._?

Comment: In Jenkins I am using This job is Build parametrized option. There I want to populate the list from JSON so that end user can select. Below is the JSON format.

`[
  {
    "namePrefix": "App_NAME",
    "maintainers": [
      "maintainer_ID"
    ]
  },
    {
    "namePrefix": "App_NAME",
    "maintainers": [
      "maintainer_ID"
    ]
  }`

Here I want the namePrefix to be populated to the choice parameters and its not active choice parameters

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you seen the [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) with the ◉ _JSON Parameter Type_?